# "Unexpected termination of the channel" jenkins slave exception

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've faced an issue when job get stucked and still waiting for an agent

```
03:43:04 Still waiting to schedule task
03:43:04 slave1 is offline
```

For some reasons, slave went offline with this error:

```
SEVERE: I/O error in channel slave1
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:77)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2760)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3235)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:914)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:376)
        at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
```

But after a few times slave went online

```
Remoting version: 3.17
This is a Unix agent
Evacuated stdout
Agent successfully connected and online
```

But job is still stucked and waiting for this agent (number of executors is 1 and node is Idle)

How to solve this problem? Because somebody says to update jenkins, somebody updated kernel, java (which is already 1.8 version) etc etc. But, this problem occurs sometimes and even Jenkins issue (https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-48850) was closed with resolution Cannot reproduce. But It affects our Nightly Product Builds sometimes :)

Comment: It might be the jnlp connection between master and agent are blocking because of some issue, If you are connecting agent to master with jnlp?

Comment: We are connecting via SSH